# How to describe json nested documents in a java class?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

JSON contains a formula and values of the parameters. For example the sum of a+b is

```
{
formula: "a+b",
values: {"a": 3, "b": 5}
}
```

For different formula json sends different list of values. I want to create a java class that includes two fields. The first one is a formula in a string format, second is an inner class:

```
class Request {
private string formula;
private Values values;
}
```

I use Spring MVC to build Restful service for this and have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/match", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Double generate(@RequestBody Request request)
{
return service.match(request);
}
```

How to make a nested class `Values` that includes all of the fields of a nested json document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private Values values;
```

to

```
private Map<String, Integer> values;
```

and then you don't need a custom class for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `class Values extends HashMap<String, Integer>{...}`

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: He means that your `Values` class should subclass `HashMap`, nothing more.